# Specify width in link_to image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the following code to link to logo on the nav bar:

```
 <%= link_to " #{image_tag ("logo3.svg")}".html_safe, root_url %>
```

I need to specify the width of the logo, but have got a little confused. Tried in/out of the brackets, with a trailing comma - breaks every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add image tag in quotes. simply do it like this

```
<%= link_to image_tag("logo3.svg",width: 500,class: 'your_class'), root_url %>
```

There is another way to do the same.

```
<%= link_to root_url do %>
 <%=image_tag("logo3.svg",width: 500)%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `image_tag` as it define [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) in `link_to` tag

Ex:

```
 <%= link_to image_tag("logo3.svg", height: 'you-height', width: 'your-width'), root_url %>
```

Hope you get the more idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
<%= link_to " #{image_tag ("logo3.svg", size: "16x10")}".html_safe, root_url %>
```

Obviously you can customize size - i gave it as an example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <%= link_to " #{image_tag ("logo3.svg",  height: '32', width: '32')}".html_safe, root_url %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can add a class name and then add css rules for width like below

```
 <%= link_to " #{image_tag ("logo3.svg")}".html_safe, root_url, :class  => "my-logo" %>
```

Then in your css file add something like below:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/some_file.css

.my-logo {

  width: your-image-width;

}
```

Those solutions would work fine but you should avoid writing inline css that is best practice.
Hope that helps.